# Is there a way to get CSS :after selector to work in Outlook?

Tags: css, outlook, css-selectors, css-tables

I have a chunk of code that allows me to have a re-sizable border for my table but it doesn't show in Outlook.

```
.column1{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative;

}

.column1:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    left: 97.5%;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

I believe it is the `:after` selector that Outlook doesn't agree with. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You are correct it does not function in Outlook, see http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for all usable selectors.

Comment: give the column after column1 a class and style based on that.

Comment: `:after` inserts content after an element, he would have to manually put the content in the column, even doing `content=''` for the next column wouldn't work because I don't think Outlook will support the content CSS attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to lack of support in Outlook for such selector as `:after` among many others, you won't be able to produce the same effect using CSS. See http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for information on the available CSS abilities of major email clients.